# SQL Server 2000 Regular Expression alternative

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I wrote a stored procedure which on several declared variables uses regular expression.

Example:

```
IF @value_criteria like '%[^0-9]%' 
   SET @having_clause = 'HAVING value_criteria <=' + @value_criteria
```

....to my latter disappointment it runs on SQL Server 2000 which does not seem to "know" reg. ex. (unless extra DLL is installed which I cannot do.)

Is there an alternative to this statement which would work for SQL Server 2000 ?

Thanks

Comment: Just to confirm - you want to set `@having_clause` IF `@value_criteria` is not numeric?

Comment: The LIKE expression (not regular expressions) is supported in SQL Server 2000.  And, the logic here appears to be backwards (if @ value_criteria has a non-numeric character, the @having_clause string is built as if the value is numeric.  I think the logic is your problem, not the lack of LIKE expression pattern handling.

Comment: ...hi there, what I was trying to accomplish was:
IF @/value_criteria IS number (and only number) THEN @/having_clause IS 'this string"....   Was I wrong ?

Comment: ..BTW thanks for voting my post down, next time please specify why.

Comment: I explained a few problems in my comment.  The premise of the question was wrong (and the reference to regular expressions was wrong so this post will waste other people's time).  LIKE is supported as any simple test would have confirmed.  And the logic was backwards (perhaps you meant NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression:

```
IF @value_criteria like '%[^0-9]%'
    SET  @having_clause = 'HAVING value_criteria <=' + @value_criteria;
```

is standard `like` syntax (for SQL Server).  This structure for the pattern is support in SQL Server 2000.  It does not require regular expressions.

The [SQL Server 2000 documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933232%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) for `like` explains the support for this type of pattern.

Comment: ...hmmm, thank you for saying that but our database begs the difference :) Let me re-try and re-check my syntax again.

Comment: Yes, you seem to be correct. I stripped my SP to just this statement and a few essentials and it seems to work, so my mistake is somewhere else though, thanks you anyway. I voted your answer up.

Comment: Actually the statement: IF (@/value_criteria like '%[^0-9]%') is for some reason still failing. Damn, it must be some other issue.

Comment: @Milan . . . I actually think you want `if @value_criteria not like '%[^0-9]%' . . .`.  That is the correct expression for finding something that consists only of integers.  Your `having` clause would fail with a non-number in `@value_criteria`.

Comment: ..oh, yes, you are right, I am negating twice here. It works. Thanks for the following up.